# RF Communication project using 2 STM32F407VG disc1 bords

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm currently in charge of a project based on the RF transaction. My project is based to develop a system that have the ability to communicate with the RF transceiver, **first I chose the AS4432SMD** developed with the **SI4432 transceiver** and I tried to connect it with the [**stm32f407G disc1**](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html);  , and I don't have any answer with it.
I do all my best with searching of any application use this type of communication, Any questions or any library for **the SI4432 **and nothing I found only this [library](https://github.com/udik-chudik/SI4432), and it didn't work.

Now I'm trying to use the [**STEVAL-IKR002V2D**](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/steval-ikr002v2d.html),developed by STMicroelectronics also nothing I found, another problem, this communication must be controlled the frequency and must support all the sub-1GHz range and all I found a module support only a small range of the **sub-1 GHz (315MHz, 433MHz ...)**.
I need your support guys, anything could help please a library or an example using the **STEVAL-IKR002V2D **with this STM32 board.

Comment: Please, give some specific information. It's all very general, and there is very little to go on. How do you connect stuff? I2C? UART? SPI? Change the question title to something more specific, add some description of how exactly things are connected. As of now, your question seems near impossible to answer, because it's hard to say what's going on